# How to combine timeline/overlaps from multiple sources

Tags: sql, sql-server, timeline

Using four sources, which overlappingt timelines for the same employee, I need to create a master timeline, that gives an accurate, unbroken, timeline for the employee where source data is used via a priority.

A> B> C >D

If a date in a timeline is covered by A, use that else B etc.

If a date is both in A and B, A is used.

If a date is not in A but in B, use B etc.

I've tried combining them using just a case when to select the appropriate source, however that requires the timelines be split out into individual dates, that works for one employee, but covering 10.000 employees its very slow.

```
/* Drop tables */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #A
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #B
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #C
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #D
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Output

/* Create temporay tables */
CREATE TABLE #A      ([TableKey] varbinary(8000),   [StartDate] date, [EndDate] date, [Source] varchar(2))
CREATE TABLE #B      ([TableKey] varbinary(8000),   [StartDate] date, [EndDate] date, [Source] varchar(2))
CREATE TABLE #C      ([TableKey] varbinary(8000),   [StartDate] date, [EndDate] date, [Source] varchar(2))
CREATE TABLE #D      ([TableKey] varbinary(8000),   [StartDate] date, [EndDate] date, [Source] varchar(2))
CREATE TABLE #Output ([TableKey] varbinary(8000),   [Team] VARCHAR(6), [StartDate] date, [EndDate] DATE, [Source] varchar(2))
/* Insert data */


INSERT INTO #A
VALUES
( 0x20e5cc5f1e06b501c65b079efe68ca60,  N'2013-09-10', N'2014-08-11', 'A' ), 
( 0x20e5cc5f1e06b501c65b079efe68ca60,  N'2014-08-11', N'2014-09-29', 'A' ), 
( 0x20e5cc5f1e06b501c65b079efe68ca60,  N'2014-09-29', N'2017-08-24', 'A' ), 
( 0x20e5cc5f1e06b501c65b079efe68ca60,  N'2017-08-24', N'2018-10-01', 'A' ), 
( 0x20e5cc5f1e06b501c65b079efe68ca60,  N'2018-10-01', N'2019-03-04', 'A' ), 
( 0x20e5cc5f1e06b501c65b079efe68ca60,  N'2019-03-04', N'2037-01-01', 'A' ), 
( 0x7ccb1e3f22333f646f6a2f8e90cdc23f,  N'2013-09-10', N'2013-11-26', 'A' ), 
( 0x7ccb1e3f22333f646f6a2f8e90cdc23f,  N'2013-11-26', N'2014-05-29', 'A' ), 
( 0x7ccb1e3f22333f646f6a2f8e90cdc23f,  N'2014-05-29', N'2014-05-31', 'A' )

INSERT INTO #B
VALUES
( 0x20e5cc5f1e06b501c65b079efe68ca60,  N'2015-06-04', N'2015-10-27', 'B' ), 
( 0x20e5cc5f1e06b501c65b079efe68ca60,  N'2015-10-28', N'2016-05-07', 'B' ), 
( 0x20e5cc5f1e06b501c65b079efe68ca60,  N'2016-05-08', N'2016-05-17', 'B' ), 
( 0x20e5cc5f1e06b501c65b079efe68ca60,  N'2016-05-18', N'2016-08-27', 'B' ), 
( 0x20e5cc5f1e06b501c65b079efe68ca60,  N'2016-08-28', N'2016-11-23', 'B' ), 
( 0x20e5cc5f1e06b501c65b079efe68ca60,  N'2016-11-24', N'2017-01-14', 'B' ), 
( 0x20e5cc5f1e06b501c65b079efe68ca60,  N'2017-01-15', N'2017-08-27', 'B' ), 
( 0x20e5cc5f1e06b501c65b079efe68ca60,  N'2017-08-28', N'2017-09-05', 'B' ), 
( 0x20e5cc5f1e06b501c65b079efe68ca60,  N'2017-09-06', N'2017-10-07', 'B' ), 
( 0x20e5cc5f1e06b501c65b079efe68ca60,  N'2017-10-08', N'2017-11-05', 'B' ), 
( 0x20e5cc5f1e06b501c65b079efe68ca60,  N'2017-11-06', N'2018-09-29', 'B' ), 
( 0x20e5cc5f1e06b501c65b079efe68ca60,  N'2018-09-30', N'2019-03-12', 'B' ), 
( 0x20e5cc5f1e06b501c65b079efe68ca60,  N'2019-03-13', N'2019-04-29', 'B' ), 
( 0x20e5cc5f1e06b501c65b079efe68ca60,  N'2019-04-30', N'2019-05-06', 'B' ), 
( 0x20e5cc5f1e06b501c65b079efe68ca60,  N'2019-05-07', N'2037-12-29', 'B' ), 
( 0x7ccb1e3f22333f646f6a2f8e90cdc23f,  N'2015-06-04', N'2015-11-13', 'B' ), 
( 0x7ccb1e3f22333f646f6a2f8e90cdc23f,  N'2015-11-14', N'2016-11-01', 'B' ), 
( 0x7ccb1e3f22333f646f6a2f8e90cdc23f,  N'2016-11-02', N'2016-12-17', 'B' ), 
( 0x7ccb1e3f22333f646f6a2f8e90cdc23f,  N'2016-12-18', N'2017-05-01', 'B' ), 
( 0x7ccb1e3f22333f646f6a2f8e90cdc23f,  N'2017-05-02', N'2017-08-06', 'B' ), 
( 0x7ccb1e3f22333f646f6a2f8e90cdc23f,  N'2017-08-07', N'2017-08-28', 'B' ), 
( 0x7ccb1e3f22333f646f6a2f8e90cdc23f,  N'2017-08-29', N'2017-10-14', 'B' ), 
( 0x7ccb1e3f22333f646f6a2f8e90cdc23f,  N'2017-10-15', N'2037-12-29', 'B' )


INSERT INTO #C
Values
( 0x65dd7602e1c376a2d991114ab4c5d28d, N'2013-09-09', N'2014-08-10', 'C' ), 
( 0x65dd7602e1c376a2d991114ab4c5d28d, N'2014-08-10', N'2014-09-28', 'C' ), 
( 0x65dd7602e1c376a2d991114ab4c5d28d, N'2014-09-28', N'2017-08-23', 'C' ), 
( 0x65dd7602e1c376a2d991114ab4c5d28d, N'2017-08-23', N'2017-09-07', 'C' ), 
( 0x65dd7602e1c376a2d991114ab4c5d28d, N'2017-09-07', N'2018-06-27', 'C' ), 
( 0x67d42e1b67016ec584092017703de16f, N'2013-09-09', N'2013-11-25', 'C' ), 
( 0x67d42e1b67016ec584092017703de16f, N'2013-11-25', N'2014-05-28', 'C' ), 
( 0x67d42e1b67016ec584092017703de16f, N'2014-05-28', N'2014-05-30', 'C' ), 
( 0x67d42e1b67016ec584092017703de16f, N'2014-05-30', N'2018-06-27', 'C' )


INSERT INTO #D
VALUES
( 0x20e5cc5f1e06b501c65b079efe68ca60, N'2015-02-14', N'2037-12-29', 'D' ), 
( 0x7ccb1e3f22333f646f6a2f8e90cdc23f, N'2015-02-14', N'2037-12-29', 'D' )
```

A single unbroken timeline example for two employees, where sources from the code is used to create the timelines.

```
/* Desired Output */
INSERT INTO #Output
VALUES
(0x20e5cc5f1e06b501c65b079efe68ca60,'Team 1',N'2013-09-10',N'2014-08-11',N'A'),
(0x20e5cc5f1e06b501c65b079efe68ca60,'Team 2',N'2014-08-11',N'2014-09-29',N'A'),
(0x20e5cc5f1e06b501c65b079efe68ca60,'Team 1',N'2014-09-29',N'2017-08-24',N'A'),
(0x20e5cc5f1e06b501c65b079efe68ca60,'Team 4',N'2017-08-24',N'2018-10-01',N'D'),
(0x20e5cc5f1e06b501c65b079efe68ca60,'Team 1',N'2018-10-01',N'2019-03-04',N'A'),
(0x20e5cc5f1e06b501c65b079efe68ca60,'Team 3',N'2019-03-04',NULL,N'A'),
(0x7CCB1E3F22333F646F6A2F8E90CDC23F,'Team 1',N'2013-09-10',N'2013-11-26','A'),
(0x7CCB1E3F22333F646F6A2F8E90CDC23F,'Team 2',N'2013-11-26',N'2014-05-29','B'),
(0x7CCB1E3F22333F646F6A2F8E90CDC23F,'Team 2',N'2014-05-29',N'2014-05-31','B'),
(0x7CCB1E3F22333F646F6A2F8E90CDC23F,'Team 3',N'2017-02-15',N'2017-03-15','C'),
(0x7CCB1E3F22333F646F6A2F8E90CDC23F,'Team 4',N'2017-03-16',NULL,N'D')
```

Comment: The first line of the desired output has `2013-09-10` until `2014-08-11` which are not dates found in your four sources. What is the logic behind this ?

Comment: I've updated the code - there was no logic. It was a copy error from a previous code attempt.

Comment: you need to explain your logic here more clearly with reference to the sample data that you have provided